# Sort by LocalDate a mapped stream

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, localdate

I have a class **client** that contains a list of **Orders**, that also contains a `LocalDate order_date`.

And using Java 8 streams, I want to sort my list of Orders by Date.

I have the following code :

`clients.getOrders().stream().map(Order::getDate).sorted(LocalDate::compareTo)).forEach(System.out::println)`

But that does absolutely not sort. I also tried with `sorted(Comparator.comparing(Order::getDate))` but it prints the same.

**EDIT** :

Dates are differents and my whole code line is this

```
clients.stream().filter(client -> client.getOrders() != null).flatMap(c -> c.getOrders().stream().map(Order::getDate).sorted(LocalDate::compareTo)).forEach(System.out::println)
```

And the output I have is

```
2019-02-17
2019-12-05
2020-03-15
2018-10-05
2020-07-15
2021-01-01

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and I want this

```
2018-10-05
2019-02-17
2019-12-05
2020-03-15
2020-07-15
2021-01-01
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Some example input and output would be good, and the version of Java that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are sorting the wrong stream. If you use `flatMap` first and then `sorted` it should work.

```
clients.stream().filter(client -> client.getOrders() != null).flatMap(c -> c.getOrders().stream()).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Order::getDate)).forEach(System.out::println)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I'm learning the stream and I thought I had to map the date of the commands but indeed it makes no sense.
Thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
It seems that the implementation in the question calls client.getOrders() many times.
Not sure if `client.getOrders()` returns the same result every time it is called. Also it is sorting only the dates, not the orders.

The following code only makes a single `client.getOrders()` invocation and sorts the orders.

```
final List<Order> orders = clients.stream().map(clients -> client.getOrders())
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.flatMap(orders -> orders.stream()) 
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Order::getDate))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
//Printing orders' dates
orders.stream().map(Order::getDate).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Information based on first question version**

Based on the original information available, this should normally work:

```
clients.getOrders().stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Order::getDate)) 
.forEach(System.out::println)
```

But you already mention you tried it.

Another way could be using collections.

```
final List<Order> orders=clients.getOrders();
Collections.sort(orders,Comparator.comparing(Order::getDate));
orders.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```